# sub query in sql error

Tags: sql-server, subquery

i want to apply sub query i do this but this shows an error

```
select          t.Tid, 
            i.Description,          
            tst.Description,
            dd.DoID,
            dd.Document,
            dd.docname  
                
    from    Ticet t 
        (
            select tid, MIN(hid) hid from TtH th group by Tid
        ) mh
    inner join DocDown dd on t.clientid=dd.Clientid
    inner join Item i on t.Itemid=i.Itemid
    inner join TStat tst on t.Status=tst.Status
    where 
     t.Status in (1, 2 )
    and gu.Userid=1926
    
    order by t.Tid
```

Errors

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'.
>
> Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, add sub query for mh:

```
select t.Tid, i.Description, tst.Description, dd.DoID, dd.Document, dd.docname  
from   Ticet t 
inner join ( select tid, MIN(hid) hid from TtH th group by Tid ) as  mh on t.Tid=mh.tid
inner join DocDown dd on t.clientid=dd.Clientid
inner join Item i on t.Itemid=i.Itemid
inner join TStat tst on t.Status=tst.Status
where t.Status in (1, 2 ) and gu.Userid=1926
order by t.Tid
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below query, u missed the `join` and condition on `t` and `mh`

```
select  t.Tid, 
        i.Description,          
        tst.Description,
        dd.DoID,
        dd.Document,
        dd.docname  

from    Ticet t 
    inner join    (
            select tid, MIN(hid) hid from TtH th group by Tid
        ) mh    on mh.tid = t.Tid
    inner join DocDown dd on t.clientid=dd.Clientid
    inner join Item i on t.Itemid=i.Itemid
    inner join TStat tst on t.Status=tst.Status
where t.Status in (1, 2 )
    and gu.Userid=1926
order by t.Tid
```

Answer (score 0):

This

```
from    Ticet t 
(
select tid, MIN(hid) hid from TtH th group by Tid
) mh
```

should be

```
   from    Ticet t 
    JOIN
        (
            select tid, MIN(hid) hid from TtH th group by Tid
        ) mh
on mh.somecol =t.somecol
and so on
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to join your sub query table...

Assuming `mh.tid = t.tid` is the join you want.

```
SELECT t.Tid, i.Description, tst.Description, dd.DoID, dd.Document, dd.docname  
FROM Ticet t 
INNER JOIN (SELECT tid, MIN(hid) hid FROM TtH th GROUP BY Tid) mh ON mh.tid = t.Tid
INNER JOIN DocDown dd ON t.clientid = dd.Clientid
INNER JOIN Item i ON t.Itemid = i.Itemid
INNER JOIN TStat tst ON t.Status = tst.Status
WHERE t.Status IN (1, 2)
AND gu.Userid = 1926
ORDER BY t.Tid
```